# Vue3 isCustomElement seems not working and vue router clash with custom element

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I have VUE3 app with vue-router using third party web components imported as custom elements, I set the `isCustomElement` option to ignore custom element, but it seems not to be taken into account.

- I set the `"vue": { "runtimeCompiler": true }` in package.json.
- I set `app.config.isCustomElement = (tag) => tag.startsWith('bdl-')` to ignore customElements in `main.js`
- I use web components - custom elements starting with `bdl-` in `About.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is an about page</h1>
    <bdl-fmi></bdl-fmi>
    <bdl-range></bdl-range>
    <bdl-chartjs-time></bdl-chartjs-time>
  </div>
</template>
```

However, it seems that it's not taken into account and the browser console log contains warning `[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: bdl-fmi` and custom elements fails to render in router view.

Tried VUE2 and the configuration `Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['bdl-chartjs']` is working and similar application with vue-router do not try to interpret third party custom elements and renders as expected.

Any thoughts on `isCustomElement` will be appreciated.

Sample with this issue can be seen at CODESANDBOX: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-router-with-bodylightjs-components-h8v50

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `app.config.isCustomElement` flag is intended for projects that use the runtime compiler, which could be enabled in a Vue CLI project via the [`runtimeCompiler`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler) flag in `vue.config.js`:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true,
}
```

But you could also resolve this without the runtime compiler by removing `app.config.isCustomElement`, and [configuring `vue-loader`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-loader) directly:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        options.compilerOptions = {
          ...options.compilerOptions,
          isCustomElement: tag => tag.startsWith('bdl-')
        }
        return options
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: package.json isn't where you would configure Vue CLI settings.  Can you link to a project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: config for webpack doesn't seem to fix the issue. Sample repo is at https://github.com/creative-connections/vue3-bdl2-sample-app and I have also sample sandbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-router-with-bodylightjs-components-h8v50

Comment: The problem is you haven't removed `app.config.isCustomElement`, so the warning remains. However, the Webpack config is taking effect, so you won't see the "unable to resolve component" warnings for the `bdi` tags.

Comment: Also note `vue.config.js` has no effect in Codesandbox because the projects there are not run with Vue CLI.

Comment: See https://github.com/creative-connections/vue3-bdl2-sample-app/pull/2

Comment: thanks for looking. Now another warning appears indicating that vue runtime tries to interpret the third party custom-element and fails: `[Vue warn]: Failed setting prop "id" on <bdl-fmi>: value idfmi is invalid. TypeError: this.au is undefined
    g aurelia-web-components.js:78
    patchDOMProp runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:458
    patchProp runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:586
    mountElement runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4007`

Comment: That error seems unrelated to the original problem, and is specific to using that bdl component library. I recommend asking that as a new question so that someone else familiar with that library can answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar - developer of that `bdl` library (exported web-components from Aurelia framework) and I'm investigating interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the problem because element-plus icon component not called correctly. I have to import `ElementPlusIconsVue` in my main.js and global register it like the following:

```
import * as ElementPlusIconsVue from '@element-plus/icons-vue'
const app = createApp(App)

for (const [key, component] of Object.entries(ElementPlusIconsVue)) {
  app.component(key, component)
}
// then I can call the icon in my vue file directly
<Refresh
 style="width:30px;cursor: pointer;float: right;"
 @click="get_bili"
/>
```